# Remove Unused Menu Locations

Tags: php, menus

I added two menus

```
register_nav_menus (
    array(
        'primary_menu' => esc_html__('Primary Menu', 'sre'),
        'footer_menu' => esc_html__('Footer Menu', 'sre'),
    )
);
```

But I'm unable to remove the two old ones, `Primary menu` and `Secondary menu`
[image]

When I use this code, it hides `Primary menu` but when I remove the code, it reappears in the list.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_default_menu', 11 );
function remove_default_menu(){
    unregister_nav_menu('primary');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're using a parent theme or a plugin that registers those menu locations. If that's the case then you shouldn't remove your last function. You need to keep the `remove_default_menu` function in your functions file.

If you are not using a parent theme or some sort of plugin than that means you are registering those menu locations yourself. If that's the case then you should check your code and remove the lines where you register them.

Comment: I knew I wasn't registering those menus but I didn't realize that this theme is using a parent theme and sure enough those menus are registered in the parent theme. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

> When I use this code, it hides Primary menu but when I remove the
> code, it reappears in the list.

This is to be expected. Nav menu locations are not persistent. They're not stored in the database. This is how many things work in WordPress. Taxonomies, post types, post statuses, widgets etc.

So the locations will only appear if `register_nav_menus()` is called and they will only be removed if `unregister_nav_menu()` is called. If you remove the code that calls `unregister_nav_menu()` then they're not going to be removed.

If you want to remove them permanently then you'd need to remove the code that's registering them in the first place. If this is happening in a parent theme or plugin then that's not an option so you will need to stick to running `unregister_nav_menu()`.